# How to open the txt file in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open the txt file in Android.

And I try the following code:

```
private static final String MESH_DATA_FILE_NAME = "test.txt";

String Path = "file://" + MESH_DATA_FILE_NAME;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Path);
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
it.setType("text/*");
startActivity(it);
```

But it show the following error at `startActivity(it);`

**`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getHost()' on a null object reference`**

Did I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could please confirm whether the text file in SD card or reside in the internal memory?

Comment: if I don't know the location of the text file.
Can I open the file ?

Comment: I am not sure, However I felt that we to need to provide the location of the file, which helps the android to find the file and fetch it's content.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:you need to build that Uri also

```
Uri builtUri= Uri.parse("base url goes here").buildUpon().build();
```

Comment: there is no such a method named build that returns Uri

Answer (score 0):

if your file in assets folder, Use This :

```
AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream istr = am.open("File.txt");
```

if you put it in resource and  raw  folder :

```
//res/raw/File.txt
InputStream istr = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.File);
```